# How to find a common suffix in two strings?

Tags: c#, .net, string

I'm trying to implement something that finds the common suffix between a number of strings, for the sake of illustrations, consider the following:

```
"The quick brown fox"
"The not so quick brown fox"
"The smelly brown fox"
"The vicious brown fox"
```

To a human, it's hopefully obvious that the common suffix here is `" brown fox"`, and my naive implementation currently takes the first pair of strings, converts them both to char arrays, and then iterates over these until a character is found to be different, I then create a new string from this, and crop it to the length, reverse it back to the correct order, and return that. I then repeat using the result from the first string with the next string in the list.

Whilst this is loosely O(N), performance of this isn't as good as I'd like, and I wondered before I spend a long time buried in the profiler if I'd missed a quicker way to do this within the .NET framework?

**EDIT:**
Taking out the double reverses (which then means we don't need to convert to char arrays) gives pretty good performance, for the record, my implementation looks a little like:

```
    private string GetCommonSuffix(string[] lines)
    {
        int lineCount = lines.GetLength(0);

        string currentSuffix = lines[0];
        int currentSuffixLength = currentSuffix.Length;
        for (int i = 1; i < lineCount; i++)
        {
            string thisLine = lines[i];
            if (!thisLine.EndsWith(currentSuffix))
            {
                int thisLineLength = thisLine.Length;
                int maxPossible = thisLineLength < currentSuffixLength ? thisLineLength : currentSuffixLength;

                if (maxPossible == 0)
                {
                    return string.Empty;
                }

                for (int j = 1; j < maxPossible; j++)
                {
                    if( currentSuffix[ currentSuffixLength - j ] != thisLine[ thisLineLength - j ] )
                    {
                        currentSuffix = currentSuffix.Substring(currentSuffixLength - j + 1, j - 1);
                        currentSuffixLength = j - 1;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return currentSuffix;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, to start with you don't need to convert the strings into char arrays. You can use indexers into the strings to fetch individual characters.

It's probably worth thinking of it as a *number* rather than a string... each pairwise comparison will give you a maximal value, and the final number (the size of the suffix) is the minimum of those maxima.

So two approaches suggest themselves:

- Start with 0 (always valid) and work your way up: check whether 1 is valid (i.e. all strings end with the same character) then move to 2 (by checking the penultimate character) etc
- Start with infinity, then do pairwise comparisons to *reduce* the maximum length. Of course you don't need to do *all* pairwise comparisons - just a comparison of each string with the first should be fine.

Personally I'd probably go with the first approach though - it won't have as good cache coherency, but I think it'll be better in some situations (e.g. many strings, all but one of which have a long common suffix.

(Of course, once you've got the length, getting the actual substring is very simple.)

Comment: The double reverse was something I spotted myself as I wrote it. A quick bit of profiling shows that it is also about as fast as always return the first element from the input array (given the real data), so I may be fussing over nothing...

Comment: Depending on the scale of the problem, and whether performance is an important requirement, it may lend itself to being solved using [Suffix Trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree). STs are specifically designed to make it easy to answer question like what is the longest common shared substring or suffix, and can do so at a cost proportional to the longest string. Here's a [decent implementation](http://code.google.com/p/csharsuffixtree/source/browse/#svn/trunk/suffixtree) in C#. Of course, if the number of strings is small and vary as the input, then STs may not be the best choice.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach seems OK.  You could iterate over all strings, not just two at a time which would save some reverses (and a lot of time if, say, the last string had no common prefix but all the others did - you'd do a lot of work for nothing with the pair wise approach)

There's also no need to reverse the current candidate common suffix until you've completed all the comparisons.

However,  you could avoid the reverses by keeping an array of indexes to where you are for each string, initialising each to the length of the string (minus 1) and work backwards from the end, iterating over all the strings.

Answer (score 0):

this might be a good candidate for Memoized recursive functions given that you may be wanting to hold onto previously calculated values.

basic example: http://weblogs.asp.net/podwysocki/archive/2008/08/01/recursing-into-recursion-memoization.aspx

or:
http://explodingcoder.com/blog/content/painless-caching-memoization-net

might fit, might be useless :)